# How to send a notification when checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

CheckBox cb1;

NotificationManager manager;
Notification myNotication;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    cb1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.notificationchk);


    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);// anything here and above seems ok(no error)

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)//"this" taskstackbuilder cannot be applied to oncheckedlistener
                    .Builder(mContext)//the mcontext is not working
                    .setContentTitle("New mail from ")
                    .setContentText("i")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .build();Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, firstpage.class);//everything inside bracket underlined red
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);//"this" taskstackbuilder cannot be applied to oncheckedlistener

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Settings.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);//cannot resolve symbol mBuilder 
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());//cannot resolve symbol mID,mBuilder 

    }//all errors marked


});//basically this,mbuilder,mID,mContext problem
```

How do I get a notification and checkbox to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to `Settings.this`

remove the second builder with mcontext.

Same with this inside intent. change it to `Settings.this`

Same with `TaskStackBuilder.create(this)` change it to `TaskStackBuilder.create(Settings.this)`

change this  `mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)` to   `builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)`

change  `mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build())` to  `mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())`

Comment: Sir, (1)When I change the .setSmallIcon, it says required android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder found android.app.notification. (3)And what if I want the intent to be firstpage.java, not settings? – Ze Qian Mok 1 hour ago

Comment: Intent is already firstpage.java. In intent we specify two parameters, first the calling activity then the landing activity. so 'Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, firstpage.class);' means that the intent is from settings to firstpage.  And regarding setsmallicon, you have already set it. If it is showing error, clear the notification import from top and re import using correct package

Answer (score 1):

You are building the notification. But you haven't notified the `NotifcationManager` yet. Check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for examples, maybe you're missing something like this?

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Unless you just missed to include it in the code snippet in your post? Do post your complete code snippets @ZeQianMok